# current time to time picker

Tags: android, time, dialog, picker

Hi everybody I am struggling with the idea of changing the time in time picker dialog upon when it is shown.

Here is a quotation from Android SDK reference regarding *onPrepareDialog* method

> Provides an opportunity to prepare a
>   managed dialog before it is being
>   shown. The default implementation
>   calls through to onPrepareDialog(int,
>   Dialog) for compatibility. Override
>   this if you need to update a managed
>   dialog based on the state of the
>   application each time it is shown. For
>   example, a time picker dialog might
>   want to be updated with the current
>   time. You should call through to the
>   superclass's implementation. The
>   default implementation will set this
>   Activity as the owner activity on the
>   Dialog

.

*onCreateDialog* method passes created dialog to *onPrepareDialog* as its parameter but how do I actually change the hours and minutes in this dialog?

Thanks

OK guys I found the answer, here is a part of my code from the PreferenceActivity:

```
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {

    if (id == DIALOG_MAX_AGE) {
        SharedPreferences myPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        int time = myPref.getInt(getString(R.string.pr_maxtmagekey), 15);
        int h = time / 100;
        int m = time - h * 100;

        ((TimePickerDialog)dialog).updateTime(h, m);

    }
}
```

updateTime does the thing.

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this:

In your onCreate() or anywhere you need, get the current time with typical Java code:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

And then, when you are setting your time picker, you do:

```
... new DatePickerDialog(this, aDateListener, year, month, day);
```

Then, when you open the time picket it will always show the current time.

Comment: Thanks Federico, actually I found out the way. In onPrepareDialog, I simply called ((TimePickerDialog)dialog).updateTime(h,m) - h and m I read actually from preferences but nevermind. In this way the time picker dialog will read the current time in the moment before it is shown and not on creation time.